# not able to include package created by own in java

Tags: java

I have written a program that checks a data set and provides a result, i.e. if a climate condition is given for 1000 days as data set to the program it will find any deviation in the program and provide as result that major deviation.

```
package main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;

import faster94.*;
import rules_agarwal.*;
import algo_apriori.*;
import context_apriori.*;
import itemsets.*;


public class MainTestAllAssociationRules {

    public static void main(String [] arg){

        ContextApriori context = new ContextApriori();
        try {
            context.loadFile(fileToPath("ds1.txt"));
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        /*catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        context.printContext();


        double minsupp = 0.5;
        AlgoApriori apriori = new AlgoApriori(context);
        Itemsets patterns = apriori.runAlgorithm(minsupp);
        patterns.printItemsets(context.size());


        double  minconf = 0.60;
        AlgoAgrawalFaster94 algoAgrawal = new AlgoAgrawalFaster94(minconf);
        RulesAgrawal rules = algoAgrawal.runAlgorithm(patterns);
        rules.printRules(context.size());

    }

    public static String fileToPath(String filename) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        URL url = MainTestAllAssociationRules.class.getResource(filename);
         return java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url.getPath(),"UTF-8");
    }
}
```

The above is the main program. There are seven files and I have created by own package, but when I run this program as a whole I cannot run it. It complains that a package is missing. i have ready provided all the seven files.

Can any one be able to run those files?

Comment: Can we see the error message?

Comment: how you run this file? show us the java command you used to run file.

Comment: Looking at your code and import statements I suggest you have a look at how Java packages are supposed to be used, possibly here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Comment: @talbicolas error msg:1 error found:
File: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\MainTestAllAssociationRules.java  [line: (no source location)]
Error: File is in the wrong directory or is declared part of the wrong package.  Directory name 'bin' does not match package name 'main'.

Comment: @Harry Joy i am using Dr java software to run this files...

Comment: Well there's clearly something wrong with the way you structured your program

Comment: @learn: I think your file (MainTestAllAssociationRules.java) is in "bin" folder which should be in folder named "main". This is what I understand from the error you have pasted.

Comment: @Harry Joy how to run the files from command prompt... i have a main pgm in "main" folder in bin folder.... and other package in bin folder?? how to run it from commmand prompt??

Comment: @talnicolas how to run the files from command prompt... i have a main pgm in "main" folder in bin folder.... and other package in bin folder?? how to run it from commmand prompt??

Comment: I don't really understand, are your sources files in the bin folder?

Comment: @learn: `java main.MainTestAllAssociationRules`

Comment: it's kinda weird that the main class is in a lower level than the others.

Answer (score 2):

Directory tree has to reflect package tree.
So if you have a class in a package named main you class file must be in a directory named main under the working directory. So if you execute from bin/ your class must be in bin/main.
Hope this helps

---

**Edit**

The directory tre has to look like this.
`bin/`
`-----faster94/`
`--------------Classes or Subpackage`
`-----rules_agarwal/`
`-------------------Classes or Subpackage`
`-----algo_apriori/`
`------------------Classes or Subpackage`
`-----context_apriori/`
`---------------------Classes or Subpackage`
`-----itemsets/`
`--------------Classes or Subpackage`
`-----main/`
`----------MainTestAllAssociationRules and other classes or subpackages`

To run this use `java main.MainTestAllAssociationRules` in the root (`bin/`) directory

Comment: how to run the files from command prompt... i have a main pgm in "main" folder in bin folder.... and other package in bin folder?? how to run it from commmand prompt??

Comment: It's the exact answer I would have gave! Be carefull when you run the program, you have to be in bin/ and run `java main.MainTestAllAssociationRules`.

Comment: Consider the bin/ folder as the root of your package tree. Other package if they are .class file have to put in the right subdirectory, if they are .jar files probably the creator of the file have been structured the archive in the right way (this mean left jar file in the root ).

Comment: Answer modified with more infos